# Record and play sound via Pulse, commandline - NOISE

Tags: audio, debian, kde-plasma, pulseaudio

I found this answer on recording and playing the sound at the same time:

https://askubuntu.com/a/724964

However, when I record it this way I get only terrible noise. I checked that the problem lies with `parec`, not with `lame` part of:

```
parec --format=s16le -d record-n-play.monitor | \
  lame -r --quiet -q 3 --lowpass 17 --abr 192 - "temp.mp3"
```

P.S.

List of sink inputs is empty for me:

```
% pacmd list-sink-inputs
0 sink input(s) available.
```